# MVC 4 with WebAPI 2 does not have a default constructor error

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, ninject

Hi i am using MVC4 and WebAPI2 and i got `does not have a default constructor` **error** in **Ninject**(which is a known error on ninject) and i used **NinjectDependencyResolver** custom class and also **WebApiContrib.Ioc.Ninject** nuget to figure out this error. here is my **NinjectWebCommon** below.

I am not sure is it because my project is layered, so the layer is like 
 I have "CompositionRoot" layer, where Ninject are added and i reference this layer to my main web layer. My project is working, but my web api doesn't return the json, Please help me, i cant move forward without getting this fixed , thanks in advance.

```cs
public static class NinjectWebCommon {
    private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

    public static void Start() {
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
        bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
    }

    public static void Stop() {
        bootstrapper.ShutDown();
    }

    public static IKernel CreateKernel() {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
        kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

        RegisterServices(kernel);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = 
            new NinjectResolver(kernel);

        // I tested using below code as well (NinjectDependencyResolver 
        // is custom class to fix this issue )        
        //GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = 
        //    new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);
        return kernel;
    }

    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel) {
        kernel.Bind<IUserBusiness>().To<UserBusiness>().InRequestScope();
        kernel.Bind<IUserDataAccess>().To<UserDataAccess>().InRequestScope();
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Drax,

You shouldn't assign your `DependencyResolver` to the GlobalConfiguration when creating the kernel at that point. The reason is because the `Start()` method usually runs on `WebActivator` which kicks-in before even the ASP.NET WebAPI subsystem or your Application starts up.

My suggestion is to move the assignment of this dependency resolver to `Global.asax` or `WebApiConfig.cs` inside your `App_Start`:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    [...]
    //Dependency Resolver configuration
    config.DependencyResolver = new NinjectResolver((new Boostrapper).Kernel);

    // Configure routes and the rest of WebAPI stuff.
}
```

And don't forget in `Global.asax` (it should be there already):

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
}
```

See if that will work out for you and let us know. If it doesn't, update the question with your `NinjectResolver` code.